# How come select in and NOT IN bring same record?

Tags: mysql, sql

How come the following two SQL statements brings some same records (MySQL) :

Statement 1:

```
SELECT distinct CountryCD, StateCD, COUNTRY, STATE 
FROM cities 
where (CountryCD,StateCD) NOT IN (
    select distinct CountryCD1,StateCD from states);
```

statement 2:

```
SELECT distinct CountryCD, StateCD, COUNTRY, STATE 
FROM cities 
where (CountryCD,StateCD) IN (
    select distinct CountryCD1,StateCD from states);
```

It seems NOT IN one does not work properly. It brings back these records in the result set of `(select distinct CountryCD1,StateCD from states)`. What's wrong?

Such as, below record is a part of both result sets:
US  CA  United States   California

Comment: why do  you select both columns countrycd and statecd . try using seperately

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion WHat is wrong with using 2 columns? If the problem demands using 2 columns, using 1 will give different results,

Comment: @uguide, are the 2 results identical? Or some of ther rows match? It would be good if you added a simple setup in [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I said try using Not in twice for 2 different columns and in same query

Comment: Two result sets are not identical, but lot of rows are the same

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative left join or an inner join to achieve these results.

Inner Join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CountryCD, c.StateCD, c.COUNTRY, c.STATE
FROM Cities c
INNER JOIN States s
    ON s.CountryCD = c.CountryCD AND s.StateCD = c.StateCD
```

Negative Left Join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CountryCD, c.StateCD, c.COUNTRY, c.STATE
FROM Cities c
LEFT JOIN States s
    ON s.CountryCD = c.CountryCD AND s.StateCD = c.StateCD
WHERE s.StateCD IS NULL
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP is getting these "weird" results.

Comment: Yes, left join or inner join works. But why NOT IN does not work? Thanks,